# HTTP Security Header Not Detected, PCI DSS

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, pci-dss

I am using this server machine to publish my web site to the world wide web;
Windows server 2012 R2 Standart, 64 bit operating system, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz 2.29 GHz (2 processors) 
I use credit card payment system module on my web site. (3D Secure Credit Card Payment with asp.net c#) So i should sign my web site as "passed" from PCI DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard) scan.

But i have got one inanition after PCI DSS scan. And i need to solve this inanition(problem). Here is the result of PCI DSS scan:

problem name :HTTP Security Header Not Detected

Port: 443

Type: 2

Category: CGI

PCI compatibility: FAIL

Fastening: X-Frame-Options or Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors HTTP Headers missing on port 443. GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: xxx.abc.com Connection: Keep-Alive X-XSS-Protection HTTP Header missing on port 443. X-Content-Type-Options HTTP Header missing on port 443. Content-Security-Policy HTTP Header missing on port 443. Strict-Transport-Security HTTP Header missing on port 443.

Please take a look screnshots from inetmgr:

[HTTP Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSxVw.png)

[cgi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WACba.png)

What should i do on my server to pass this problem? Thanks.